# Exercism assignment for word-count in Clojure

Tags: clojure, exercism

I would appreciate some insights / comments from Clojure regulars out there about my submission [here](https://github.com/exercism/exercism.io/tree/master/assignments/clojure/word-count).

```
(ns phrase)
(require '[clojure.string :as s])

(defn word-array
  [phrase]
  (-> (s/lower-case phrase)
      (s/split #"\W+")))

(defn word-count
  [phrase]
  (-> (word-array phrase)
      (frequencies)))
```

Comment: It seems like a copy of the example code provided in the linked repository. What kind of feedback would you like about it ?

Comment: Well I think it's a little bit shorter than the example. I just reworked my solution until I got the shortest form of it. I just wanted some comments on if this is like succinct clojure code and is it idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

I would format it like this:

```
(ns phrase
  (:require [clojure.string :as s]))

(defn word-array [phrase]
  (s/split (s/lower-case phrase) #"\W+"))

(defn word-count [phrase]
  (frequencies (word-array phrase)))
```

Notice that I included the `require` statement as part of the `ns` definition.

Whether or not you use threading macros (`->`, `->>`) is generally a matter of personal preference, and there's nothing wrong with using them here, but I think in this case since you're only using 2 functions, I find the above easier to read. You might also consider using `comp`:

```
(def word-array (comp #(s/split % #"\W+") s/lower-case)
(def word-count (comp frequencies word-array))
```